# "Наконец" — знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, нужно ли в данном случае выделять слово "наконец" запятыми?

**Летом состоится встреча выпускников — весь наш класс наконец соберется вместе.**

И ещё: верно ли я поставила тире?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все знаки препинания поставлены верно.

1) Слово НАКОНЕЦ здесь является обстоятельством (значение "наконец-то"). Сравнить: Добрая Прасковья Петровна радовалась, что дочь ее наконец нашла себе достойного жениха. О бедность! Затвердил я наконец урок твой горький! Давал три бала ежегодно и промотался наконец.

2) Слово НАКОНЕЦ является вводным словом, если:

а) выражает связь мыслей автора, порядок их изложения, завершает перечисление: 
Один засмеялся, за ним второй, десятый, сотый и, наконец, последний. Да и наконец, всегда лучше впасть в ошибку, думая хорошо.

б) выражает нетерпение: Да оставьте меня, наконец!

3) Тире выражает причинно-следственную связь предложений в БСП.

Comment: София, спасибо Вам, что помогаете!